# can any body tell me why static block is called when i am calling the static variable only

Tags: java

```java
package hello;

class hellogy {
    static
    
    {
        System.out.println("i will obviously enter hera");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( dls.i);
}
}
class dls
{
    
static int i=10;
static
    
    {
        System.out.println("i will obvioussadsfaasly enter hera");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the class has to get loaded. The static block executes as part of the class loading.

Comment: When would you *expect* the static block to be executed?

Comment: As @NathanHughes says, all static blocks are loaded once at the class initialization. If you call the static more than one time you will see the static printing only at the first call.

Answer (score 1):

Static block in Java is executed before main method. If we declare a static block in java class it is executed when class loads.